# Error in accessing parameters from fulfillment in dialogflow in-line editor

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

A. Steps I did

1. Created new bot
2. Created entity visaCountry with @sys.geo-country.country
3. Created Intent named getVisaCountry and called entity in parameters.
4. Check $visaCountry set correctly as parameters in text response.
5. Connected intent with fulfillment
6. updated versions to latest in package.json to

   ```
           "@google-cloud/firestore": "^0.16.1",
            "actions-on-google": "^2.12.0",
            "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
            "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
            "dialogflow": "^0.6.0",
            "googleapis": "^27.0.0",
            "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.1",
            "request": "^2.85.0",
            "uuid": "^3.0.1"
   ```
7. Added admin rights in index.js

   ```
            var admin = require('firebase-admin');
            var app = admin.initializeApp();
   ```
8. Mapped intent

   ```
             intentMap.set('getVisaCountry', ffVisaCountry);
   ```
9. Created function ffVisaCountry
10. Called parameter  visaCountry in funcation.
11. Response was `[object object]`

B. My Code

```js
    'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var app = admin.initializeApp();


process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
 
  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }
 
  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }
  
  function ffVisaCountry(agent) {
   let visaCountry = agent.parameters.visaCountry;
    agent.add(`FF reply: ${visaCountry}`);  
  }

'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('getVisaCountry', ffVisaCountry);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

C. I tried following Alternate Arguments.

1. Replacing let with const and var
2. Moving argument out of function bracket
3. Replacing  `agent.parameters.visaCountry;` with `agent.parameters['visaCountry'];`
4. Tried adding context

D. Intended and actual behavior of the agent

Intended behavior: FF reply: {name of country typed by user}

Actual behavior: FF reply: [object Object]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Although your question is very detailed, it would also help if you updated the question with a screen shot of the Dialogflow configuration for the Intent where you have the issue - the `getVisaCountry` Intent in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `visaCountry` is a JavaScript Object and not a String. When you try to convert it into a String in the line

```
agent.add(`FF reply: ${visaCountry}`);
```

JavaScript doesn't know how to do so, so it represents it as a generic string "[object Object]".

If you just want to see the object notation, you can use the `JSON.stringify()` method to convert the object to a JSON string. Something like this

```
agent.add(`FF reply: ${JSON.stringify(visaCountry)}`);
```

might give you this result

```
{ "name": "Canada", "alpha-2": "CA", "numeric": 124, "alpha-3": "CAN" }
```

If you just wanted the ISO-3166-1 country code, you could access it with something like

```
let countryCode = visaCountry['alpha-2'];
```

But why is Dialogflow sending an Object?

You don't show the Intent you're using, but if you're using the `@sys.geo-country-code` entity type, then Dialogflow sends that to your fulfillment [as an object](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/system-entities).

If you just want the name, then you can use the `@sys.geo-country` entity type. This will send it as a string in the language of the current locale for your agent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for prompt answers.
As you mentioned correctly I was using hybrid entity "visaCountry" in my intent "getVisaCountry". 
As per your solution, i used @sys.geo-country as parameter in said intent, issue resolved.
Thanks for your support and technically perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

However, for using parameters derived from hybrid entities in intent 
(Not the system entities like @sys.geo-country)

code shall be written as

agent.add(`FF reply: ${visaCountry['geo-country']}`);

Thanks.